# Does the index a bucket changes when rehashing occurs?

Tags: java, hash, hashmap, hashtable, hashcode

In a simple design of a hashtable, the hashcode of an object will mod with the num of the buckets to produce an index. The object will be put into the bucket of this index. 
My question is that when rehashing occurs, the num of buckets doubling itself, at this time does every object need to recalculate the index, hashcode mod with the new num?  I guess is yes. 
I will be appreciated if anyone walks me through the rehashing process more clearly.

Answer (score 1):

Yes in rehashing every element would move to their own new bucket based on hashcode and new size. See [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Hashtable.html#rehash%28%29) document for simple one liner.